# Function to convert webcolor html colour name to hex in Go | DarkOrange -> #FF8C00

Tags: html, go, colors

I'm trying to convert a webcolor name like DarkOrange, although ideally it would be able to parse lowercase (darkorange), into the hex for that colour #FF8C00

I've noticed that Go does include the colornames package which returns the RGBA

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/image/colornames"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    lightyellow := colornames.Lightyellow
    fmt.Println("colour rgba: ", lightyellow)
}
```

But I want to be able to write a function that I can pass the webcolor name in, and get out the hex:

```
func convertWebToHex(webcolorname string)(hexcolor string){
    PLEASE HELP WITH THIS
    return hexcolor
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple solution

The package [`golang.org/x/image/colornames`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/image/colornames) also contains an exported `Map` variable which maps from lowercased color names to [`color.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA).

So simply use this map to lookup the color for a name, and convert the RGB components to hex representation:

```
func convertWebToHex(webcolorname string) (hexcolor string) {
    c, ok := colornames.Map[webcolorname]
    if !ok {
        // Unknown name
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", c.R, c.G, c.B)
}
```

Testing it:

```
names := []string{
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "lightyellow",
    "invalid",
}
for _, name := range names {
    fmt.Printf("%-12s: %s\n", name, convertWebToHex(name))
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pFgLP2NCWjn)):

```
red         : #FF0000
yellow      : #FFFF00
lightyellow : #FFFFE0
invalid     :
```

#### Case insensitive solution

If you want to lookup colors in a case insensitive manner, use [`strings.ToLower()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower) to convert the name to lowercase, then proceed to lookup:

```
func convertWebToHex(webcolorname string) (hexcolor string) {
    c, ok := colornames.Map[strings.ToLower(webcolorname)]
    if !ok {
        // Unknown name
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", c.R, c.G, c.B)
}
```

Testing it:

```
names := []string{
    "Red",
    "yELLOW",
    "LightYellow",
    "invalid",
}
for _, name := range names {
    fmt.Printf("%-12s: %s\n", name, convertWebToHex(name))
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jci6kvJZG8S)):

```
Red         : #FF0000
yELLOW      : #FFFF00
LightYellow : #FFFFE0
invalid     :
```

#### Pre-calculated hex values

Also note that if you have to do these lookups frequently, it might be profitable to create your own map, where you map from color name to the generated hex string, so you don't have to convert from `color.RGBA` to hex string all the time.

This is how this pre-calculated map solution looks like:

```
var colorMap = map[string]string{}

func init() {
    for name, c := range colornames.Map {
        colorMap[name] = fmt.Sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", c.R, c.G, c.B)
    }
}

func convertWebToHex(webcolorname string) (hexcolor string) {
    // invalid color results in the zero value ""
    return colorMap[strings.ToLower(webcolorname)]
}
```

Testing and output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-wj5rAtdluh).